# Azure AD with multiple Reply URLs redirects to the wrong one

Tags: azure-active-directory, ws-federation

I have an application that uses AAD with WS Federation. I have multiple Reply URLs configured in my application in my AAD. My application was previously forcing all users to sign-in, and the redirect worked correctly in all environments. I had to enable non-authenticated users access to my site, and after I've made the required changes the application started redirecting me to random Reply URL after sign in.

Here are the code changes:

Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
    ...
</system.web>
```

AccountController.cs

```
public ActionResult SignIn()
{
    WsFederationConfiguration config = FederatedAuthentication.FederationConfiguration.WsFederationConfiguration;

    string callbackUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
    SignInRequestMessage signinMessage = new SignInRequestMessage(new Uri(config.Issuer), callbackUrl);
    signinMessage.SetParameter("wtrealm", IdentityConfig.Realm ?? config.Realm);

    return new RedirectResult(signinMessage.WriteQueryString());
}
```

I also have the Reply URL specified in my Web.config transforms in two places:

In appSettings  `<add key="ida:RedirectURI" value="..." />` which is used in my Global.asax.cs in `WSFederationAuthenticationModule_RedirectingToIdentityProvider` method to set `e.SignInRequestMessage.Reply`.

And in

```
<system.identityModel.services>
    <federationConfiguration>
      <wsFederation 
              passiveRedirectEnabled="true" 
              reply="..." />
    </federationConfiguration>
</system.identityModel.services>
```

Please note that there is a related SO question which is not as detailed and is unanswered [Azure Active Directory Reply URL not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384903/azure-active-directory-reply-url-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in the SignIn method, namely in this line:

```
return new RedirectResult(signinMessage.WriteQueryString());
```

that needed to be changed to this one:

```
return new RedirectResult(signInRequest.RequestUrl.ToString());
```

Please see my blog post with a full code sample:

[Partial authentication in Azure AD using WS Federation](http://do4urka.com/partial-authentication-with-azure-active-directory-with-ws-federation-in-an-mvc-application/)