# Error creating ASP web page with single sign on over AAD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

I'm struggling with creating an ASP web page with SSO like in this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory but first I got redirected to localhost after deploying the aplication, so I searched and found the solution in [ASP.Net redirecting to local host after authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851120/asp-net-redirecting-to-local-host-after-authentication). But now when I autenticate on the web page I've created I get the next error

```
[ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to     specification starting at index 152.]
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5778570
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +124
System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +95
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +59
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +27
System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +167
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) +61
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +87
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c) +12
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext) +360
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection) +269
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +32
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +127
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +13
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ProviderName() +11
System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context) +92
System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +515
    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +18
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext() +15
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() +38
System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +83
pruebamvc.Models.ADALTokenCache..ctor(String signedInUserId) +380
pruebamvc.Startup.<ConfigureAuth>b__7_0(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification context) +111
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +4931
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__1a.MoveNext() +6453
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<BaseInitializeAsync>d__0.MoveNext() +571
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +255
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +182
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.<Invoke>d__0.MoveNext() +638
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<RunApp>d__5.MoveNext() +182
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +92
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.<DoFinalWork>d__2.MoveNext() +180
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +69
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +64
System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +380
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I've searched if anybody else has got the same error, but not success. I have tried to update nuget packages because it looks like a parsing error with the tokem, but in Startup.Auth.cs sais that authenticationcontext has AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode deprecated so I tried to replace old code

```
AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                        AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                        code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
```

with:

```
AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                        code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                        return ;
                    }
```

But still etting errors. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > but first I got redirected to localhost after deploying the apllication

You could change the redirect url both in web.config and azure ad application , please follow below steps :

1. After deploy , you will get the published app url :https://webapplicationname.azurewebsites.net/ , cope the url and modify the web config :

   ```
   <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="https://webapplicationname.azurewebsites.net/" />
   ```
2. In azure portal ,click Azure AD blade, click "App registrations" button , find the app you registered . You could find the app by app id(client id) , that could be find in web config:

   ```
   <add key="ida:ClientId" value="ae7afda3-b24b-42a7-bb14-8d7a08227f66" />
   ```

   [image]
3. select the app , click "Reply URLs" button , add the published app url(this demo i used webapplication420170330110754 as my app name ,change that to your own app name ) ,click save button:

   [image]
4. Now you need to re-publish the app to make the new web.config available .

Edit :

For this error ,please firstly confirm whether you have set the correct connect string . You could find the connect string of azure sql :
[image]
Click the connect string you will get that :
[image]

Comment: I' ve done that, and I got redirected to the url of the web page appname.azurewebsites.net after log in, but then is when I get the error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 152" which I wrote the trace in the post. I have tried with VS 2015 and 2017 getting the same error. And my ASP is updated. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @DavidMuMi ,that seems a sql server error , what is your connect string in web config ? Do you correctly config the azure sql databse and use its connect string ?

Comment: Oh my... I have finally resolved the problem. Researching with the connection string I found out that  I was using the default string in connectionString tag, when I used  the connectionString provided by your solution an error appeared because I use the symbol " in my password. So I changed my db username password and now everything works fine. Thank you for everything I've been five days with this and I wouldn't had found the solution without you.

Comment: @DavidMuMi glad to hear that you have solved your problem . If my reply helps you , you could mark this reply as answer which helps others who meet same problem as yours .