# ASP.Net redirecting to local host after authentication VSTS CI Build

Tags: asp.net, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a build task setup for a Development branch in my VSTS which publishes my ASP.Net Web application to a specific (dev) deployment slot.

The application uses AAD Authentication. When debugging locally i am able to authenticate with my AAD and am then redirected to the main page (https://localhost:44354/)

When i build to the slot and attempt to login the exact same happens, upon authentication i am redirected to https://localhost:44354/

I have had a similar issue in the past when using one click deployment which was solved by specifying the domain in the publish wizard as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851120/asp-net-redirecting-to-local-host-after-authentication/39883503#39883503)
This specific build is for a development branch which as stated above, builds to the Development Slot (with a slightly different URL to the production site)

So the question is, how can i specify this setting within my build configuration in VSTS to accommodate for Development and Production slots?

Or is there an alternative method?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Azure App Service Deploy](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment)** task in your build definition to deploy the app to development slot.

After specify **Azure subscription** and **Azure App service**, you can select **Deploy to slot** to set the slot you want to deploy.

**Note:** If the option deploy to slot is not selected, then the Azure App Service will be deployed to the Production slot.

Comment: Yes this is what i have setup and it does work. My question is why does my application (deployed to development slot) redirect to localhost after login?

Comment: What's the result if you use detail steps as the link shows https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-webapps#swap-deployment-slots?

Comment: Unfortunately i'm unable to swap slots currently with the production slot as its currently in use and would potentially cause disruption. I've swapped with swapped Dev with Staging slots which gives the same results (localhost after login)

Answer (score 0):

When you use the publish wizard in Visual Studio to publish the web app, it will generate a publish profile which contains all the required settings. Check in that file into source control, and then add one more argument `/p:PublishProfile="eddpub - Web Deploy.pubxml"` in the VS Build step in your build definition.