# Error using VS2017 & Azure - redirecting authentication from Azure to local PC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I got an error which seems to be one of the common issues. I read the whole bunch or articles, but nothing seems to be working.

I am developing a small app in Azure using VS 2017 .NET (not Core). The app requires Azure AD authentication. Everything was working fine until yesterday.

This is what's happening now:

1. The application compiles and runs on the local PC (Win 10) with no problems.
2. Local application is using Azure AD with no problem to log in and out.
3. I am deploying it to Azure from inside Visual Studio (as usual) - no problem
4. Application runs in Azure with no problem as long as NO login is required.
5. If I have to log in (click Log In or by accessing controller which requires authorization) I get the error:

   Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'AzureTest.MvcApplication'.

So far I checked:

- namespaces - OK
- rebuild, restart - OK
- I created a completely new application in Azure and in VS2017, totally fresh. Still the same behavior.
- I tried going back to VS2015 and creating a new test
  application both in VS and in Azure - still the same issue. Again, this happens only when I try to log in    using Azure AD

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!

PS - one more comment: parsing error happens when Azure site redirects me to local https://localhost:44397/. If my local app is running, then I just open it fine. So I guess this is authentication error, rather then parsing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used to leverage the [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect/) middleware to integrate Azure AD authentication with my web application.

> one more comment: parsing error happens when Azure site redirects me to local https://localhost:44397/. If my local app is running, then I just open it fine. So I guess this is authentication error, rather then parsing?

For your scenario, you need to make sure the authentication of your web application could work as expected in your local side. When deploy to Azure side, you need to change the `RedirectUri` in your web.config file and point to your azure web app domain. Moreover, here is the detailed tutorial about [Integrate Azure AD into a web application using OpenID Connect](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the Azure based URL as a Reply URL in the Azure application registration, and make sure that your application uses that when authenticating to Azure AD.

If you create a standard ASP.NET MVC Application from the Visual Studio 2017 template, it will create a file called "Startup.Auth.cs" in the "App_Start" folder.

In the call to `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` add a `RedirectUri`property to the `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies!

[I found the link here today:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851120/asp-net-redirecting-to-local-host-after-authentication)

Not sure why that box was unchecked in publishing profile, I did not change anything since I published it before. I don't even see it unless I go into settings.. Anyways, this solved the problem.
Thanks again!