# AAD registered Azure Functions + GraphAP Delegated + SharePoint Online?

Tags: authentication, graph, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, sharepoint-online

If my Azure function app and SPO are registered in the same AAD.  Can GraphAPI Delegated be used to write to SPO Lists as the **calling/current user** without additional authentication?

If so, do i need auth library code for this like ADAL? Why? Any good guides or examples?

A team member is trying and having this problem with Reply URL:
[Azure Active Directory Reply URL not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30384903/azure-active-directory-reply-url-not-working-as-expected)

Comment: How are your users authenticating to SharePoint? ADFS?

Comment: Yes I think so, but both Azure functions and SPO are registered to the same AAD.

Comment: Are you asking how to write the AD token exchange code to convert from the incoming token to the SPO token?  (ie, you'd have the same question if this was WebAPI instead of Azure Functions)

Comment: Thank You. If both our Azure Function and SPO use the same SSO and are registered to the same AAD. Sorry, why do we need to write any AD token exchange to convert tokens. Is it not the same token?  Getting clarification here internally.

Answer (score 1):

AD tokens represent more than just the current user. They also include claims about who issued the token, and the "audience" (who is allowed to consume a token). The tokens are usually JWTs and can be decoded  via a tool like http://jwt.calebb.net/.  The token for your web app very likely has a different "audience" than the token for sharepoint online. **You'll need to do a "token exchange" to get a token with the correct audience**. ADAL can do the exchange for you (see AcquireTokenAsync). There's a start of a Azure Functions binding that does token exchange for AD (the relevant part for you is: see https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-microsoftgraph-extension/blob/master/src/TokenBinding/AadClient.cs#L49 ), but it's in preview.

Note there's nothing Azure Functions /WebAPI specific here - this is purely AD and you could test this (the token exchange code) in a console app.