# Deployment Slot Swap imperfect if one of the slots uses WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE and serves Authorized files

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

This is my deployed and working .NET Framework ASP.NET MVC controller method:

```cs
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Map()
    {
       string plantMapFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myCorp:MapPdf"];
       return File($"~/App_Data/{plantMapFile}", "application/pdf");
    }
```

Unlike other MVC methods in my application, this one returns a file out of the `App_Data` folder

### My Deployment Technique

I'm using DevOps CI pipeline to build a new artifact, and an Azure DevOps
Release pipeline to deploy the artifact to the 'test' slot of my WebApp - the code shown above is actually already deployed and already working, and is not really the subject matter of my deployment.

Because my Release pipeline hadn't been used in 18mos. I had to revise it after noticing my service account credentials had gone sideways. Nothing I did seemed to fix it, so I had to make a new release pipeline. In the process of making a new release pipeline I came to realize I must have inadvertantly been introduced to this new WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE feature.

Everything tests ok on my test slot.. the aforementioned method works fine, in addition to my new changes.

When it came time to swap to production I noticed the new Configuration setting, and blessed it onwards.

I'm testing various aspects of my application (the other parts of it that require [Authorize] methods work ok, if we are talking typical MVC web pages) but the above method returned [502 Bad Gateway errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502)

Restarting the web app did not help. Re-swapping didn't help. Removing the RUN_FROM... Configuration setting made the app serve up some wacky really outdated files.

My only remedy was to re-tool my release pipeline to use Web Deploy. Then when I swapped the weird configuration setting was not presented to me as an orphaned setting. Everything seemed to work ok after that.

My question is: Is this a bug?

---

Pertinent packages:

```xml
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="AutoMapper" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" requireReinstallation="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept" version="2.0.6" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel" version="2.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.7" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient" version="2.0.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="2.0.1" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="5.2.8" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocol.Extensions" version="1.0.4.403061554" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="5.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net452" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.20" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.4.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.6.2" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.3" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="Owin" version="1.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.2.0" targetFramework="net452" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="6.7.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net472" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net462" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net452" />
```

StartupAuth.cs

```cs
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();


    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
        new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = Authority,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            RedirectUri = loginRedirectUri,//added for local dev, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31365652/1520850
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidAudiences = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audiences"].ToString().Split(';'),
                RoleClaimType = "roles"
            },
            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
            {
                // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToMicrosoft
            },
            CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager())
        });

    //Tell antiforgery to use the name claim
    AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType;
}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce this error now?

Comment: It happened just this past week. I believe I could. I think I'm now actually having the opposite problem where my App_Data PDF files are being served successfully but I cannot serve out my traditional MVC controller HtmlResult views